# Pygame creating keyboard animation

Tags: python, animation, pygame

```
   import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("TEST2")

black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)

moveX,moveY=0,0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Sprite:

    def __init__(self,x,y):

        self.x=x

        self.y=y

        self.width=50

        self.height=50

        self.i1=pygame.image.load("Sprite0.PNG")

        self.i2 = pygame.image.load("Sprite1.PNG")

        self.i3 = pygame.image.load("Sprite2.PNG")

        self.i4 = pygame.image.load("Sprite3.PNG")

        self.i5 = pygame.image.load("Sprite4.PNG")

        self.i6 = pygame.image.load("Sprite5.PNG")

        self.i7 = pygame.image.load("Sprite6.PNG")

        self.i8 = pygame.image.load("Sprite7.PNG")

        self.i9 = pygame.image.load("Sprite8.PNG")

        self.i10 = pygame.image.load("Sprite9.PNG")

        self.i11 = pygame.image.load("Sprite10.PNG")

        self.i12 = pygame.image.load("Sprite11.PNG")

        self.timeTarget=10

        self.timeNum=0

        self.currentImage=0

    def update(self):
        self.timeNumber+=1

        if(self.timeNume==self.timeTarget):

            if (self.currentImage==0):

                self.currentImage+=1

            else:
                self.currentImage=0

            self.timeNum=0

        self.render()

    def render(self):

        if (self.currentImage==0):

            window.blit(self.i1, (self.x,self.y))

        else:

            window.blit(self.i2, (self.x,self.y))

player=Sprite(100,150)
gameLoop = True
while gameLoop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:

            gameLoop = False

        if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):

            if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):

                moveX = -3

            if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):

                moveX = 3

            if (event.key==pygame.K_UP):

                moveY = -3

        if (event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):

            moveY = 3

        if (event.type==pygame.KEYUP):

            if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):

                moveX=0

            if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):

                moveX=0

            if (event.key==pygame.K_UP):

                moveY=0

            if (event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):

                moveY=0

    window.fill(black)

    player.x+=moveX

    player.x+=moveY

    player.update()

    clock.tick(50)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

So heres my problem I want to make a moving keyboard animation and when I click run not even a window pops up, Idle doesn't seem to have an errors with the code but nothing happens when I click run. if you see an error I have please tell me im trying to learn this whole pygame thing still and im quite new to python in general. Thanks!

**edit**: (I found the error I think but don't know how to fix it still)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Trevor/Downloads/TEST/images/TEST2", line 84, in <module>
    player=Sprite(100,150)
  File "C:/Users/Trevor/Downloads/TEST/images/TEST2", line 28, in __init__
    self.i0=pygame.image.load("Sprite0.PNG")
error: Couldn't open Sprite0.PNG
```

Comment: Now you have problem with image - check `Sprite0.PNG` in some viewer - or replace it with new image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to run the script in the directory where you put Sprite0.png. First use `cd` to change to that directory then run the script using `python myprogram.py`. Or you can use an absolute path for loading. So instead of `pygame.image.load("Sprite0.PNG")`, you would do `pygame.image.load("my/path/to/Sprite0.png")`

Comment: okay yeah that worked thanks! The image works but it seems to be only the first 2 images of the animation is there a way to somehow add all the images into the animation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You can load all the image the same way

Comment: I see what you mean. Your render function only draws the first two frames. That is why

Comment: okay so I `window.blit` the rest of the images under else in my render function and for some reason the images when I run are overlapping. there must be something else I must add or is it just something to do with my images possibly?

Comment: You need to fill the screen with black before you update the image, or else the last image will still be there. `window.fill(pygame.Color("black"))`

Answer (score 2):

The above error tells you exactly what it could not do.

There are two things you could do. Use `cd` to enter the directory of the images, and move them to the directory of your program.

You could also use the **path** to the image, for example:

Instead of `image.png`, if the image was in my home directory I would use `/Users/ZenOfPython/image.png`.